# Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home (cloud9, coder manual)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, heroku, sass, cloud9-ide

I'm doing this online course on coder manual. it uses cloud9 ide . what we did is edit the gemfile to macth the course video and then bundle install. we have setup gihub and heroku, created a basic html 'home.html.erb' and 'about.html.erb' pages. then we wanted add bootstrap which required adding our 'application.scss' in the '../app/assets/stylesheets/' folder by instering this text:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

this produces an error which i'm unable to fix. none of the solutions that worked for other people worked for me and i have no choice but to ask for help.

the error comes up no matter what's written after '@import'.

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home

Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.
Load paths:

  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/images

  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/javascripts

  /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/assets/stylesheets

  /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/assets/javascripts

  /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/assets/stylesheets

  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/assets/javascripts

  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/jquery-rails-4.0.3/vendor/assets/javascripts

  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.0/lib/assets/javascripts
```

Extracted source (around line #18):

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";


Rails.root: /home/ubuntu/workspace

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:18

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__982791791456713685_42695920'
```

SOLVED
1. make sure you have bootstrap gems in your Gemfile (e.g. gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.1')
2. exit the server and run it again
3. you should get a error message saying you should run 'bundle install' command
4. if you get another error message run 'bundle update' command
5. now you should be able to run the server again without errors

Comment: [link](https://tri-ronca.c9.io/) - hope you can see this

Comment: The error says "File to import not found or unreadable".  Do you not understand what it means that the file doesn't exist? Or do you have the file, but it is throwing the error for no reason?

Comment: i have no clue where these files are supposed to be. github says all i have to do is add the two import lines into 'application.scss' and that's it.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) - this one

Comment: Are you using Ruby on Rails?  Did you update your gem file like it says?

Comment: yes, ruby on rails and yes, the gem is there: gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.1'

Comment: thanks for you effort, mr. cimmanon. another user fixed the issue for me. all i had to do is run the bundle install command. i think you were about to suggest that as well. i had problems and timeouts with running the server and with both bundle install and bundle update commands so the issue stuck around.